# Area in R2 bounded by 4 curves

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

What's the area between:

$$y = 5x$$
$$y = 15x$$
$$xy = 8$$
$$xy = 4$$
?

I calculated all the points of intersection and got a double integral that looks something like this: $$\int_{\frac{2}{\sqrt15}}^{\frac{2\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 5}} \int_{5x}^{15x} 1 \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy$$

This doens't seem right but I'm not sure why. Any help would welcome!

Comment: Did you draw the region of integration?

Comment: Yes. The points for second integral are the minimum x and the maximum x respectively. I'm having trouble understand it because right now the integral is as if I'm integrating a trapezoid, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: The problem seems strange, because $xy = 8$ doesn't help define the region: http://tinyurl.com/m2y6jsx

Comment: I guess that the question doesn't refer to the triangle, but to the shape to the right of it. I don't know what kind of a coordinate change would help here; polar coordinates don't seem to be leading anywhere. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the area by a change of variables

$$(u,v) = \left(xy,\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

To compute the integral in new coordinates, you need the value of the
[Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant):

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\quad\stackrel{def}{=}\quad
\left|\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{matrix}\right|
$$

Instead of computing this explictly, one can obtain it by manipulatiing the "area element" in an algebraic manner. We have

$$dx \wedge dy = dx \wedge d(xv) = x dx \wedge dv = \frac12 d(x^2) \wedge dv
= \frac12 d\frac{u}{v} \wedge dv = \frac{du \wedge dv}{2v}$$

This implies up to a sign, the Jacobian determinant is

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \frac{1}{2v}$$

In the new coordinates $(u,v)$, the area becomes an integral over a rectangle
$[4,8] \times [5,15]$, i.e.
$$\begin{align}
\verb/Area/ 
&=  \int_{[4,8]\times[5,15]} \left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right| du dv
=  \frac12 \int_4^8 \left[ \int_5^{15} \frac{dv}{v}\right] du\\ 
&= \frac12 (8-4)\big[ \log 15 - \log 5 \big] = 2\log 3
\end{align}$$

Comment: Didn't think about it this way. Thanks for this!

Comment: Can I ask what the $\land$ symbols mean in this context, @achille and @John?

Comment: @KhallilBenyattou It is the "wedge product" between the [differential forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form). "differential forms" is a coordinate free way of dealing with multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

I try to draw the above curves using matlab, and  the enclosed area can be found as follow: $$A=\int_{\sqrt\frac{4}{15}}^{\sqrt\frac{8}{15}} \int_{\frac{4}{x}}^{15x}1 dydx + \int_{\sqrt\frac{8}{15}}^{\sqrt\frac{4}{5}} \int_{\frac{4}{x}}^{\frac{8}{x}}1 dydx  + \int_{\sqrt\frac{4}{5}}^{\sqrt\frac{8}{5}} \int_{5x}^{\frac{8}{X}}1 dydx  $$